# At what point in the boot process are systemd generators run?

Tags: init, systemd, coreos, coreos-ignition

The [systemd.generator man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html) says that generators are run very early at bootup and that they are all run at the same time. At what point in the bootup are they actually run?

As I understand it, CoreOS's [ignition](https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/) is implemented as a generator which runs [after the initramfs is mounted but before pivoting to the root filesystem](https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/boot-process.html#early-user-space), is this a CoreOS specific thing or is this common to any OS using systemd init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At what point in the bootup are they actually run?

They run every time the systemd-pid1 manager is started: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v235/src/core/manager.c#L1333

In practice, this means either as one of the very first steps when pid1 is executed or after a daemon-reload. The latter also includes the  transition between initramfs and the real rootfs.

> ignition is implemented as a generator

Ignition is not implemented as generator, but as a first-boot initramfs service. If you read any doc page stating that ignition is a systemd generator, please report a bug against that as it is incorrect.

> is this a CoreOS specific thing or is this common to any OS using systemd init?

Ignition is a CoreOS specific component. It is open-source and can be ported to any systemd-based distribution, but I am not aware of any other distribution using it. See https://github.com/coreos/ignition

Comment: Awesome, I think I just misinterpreted [this](https://coreos.com/ignition/docs/latest/what-is-ignition.html#when-is-ignition-executed) - so I guess the ignition units are just set up using a generator

Comment: Ignition execution is split across different stages (disks, files, quench), which are installed as normal systemd service units in initramfs via dracut: https://github.com/coreos/bootengine/tree/4d25b96ce6aab8ae4ecd6532ab4ea81a51dcfe00/dracut/30ignition